# cannot get the object from the gridView

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, onitemclicklistener

I am created a view of current week using `GridView`. I use a `BaseAdapter` for generating the `GridView`.

this is how i give values to the `GridView`

```
        ArrayList<WeekCellItem> weekCellItems = getData(scheduleListdto);
    gridview1.setAdapter(new WeekAdapter(getApplicationContext(),weekCellItems));
```

And I need the `CurrentItem` at postion when i clicked on each cell on the `GridView`.

I wrote the `onItemClickListener` for the `GridView`

```
gridview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Object o= gridview1.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Log.e("", "hhh");
        }
    });
```

I get the object 'o' as null.

(EDIT)

my weekAdapter

```
public class WeekAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Context mycontext;
ArrayList<String>weekHeads;
ArrayList<WeekCellItem> weekCellItems;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public WeekAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<WeekCellItem> items, ArrayList<String> obj)
{
    weekCellItems=items;
    weekHeads=obj;
    mycontext=c;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return weekCellItems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int pos, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewHolder holder = new viewHolder();
    if(convertview==null)
    {
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekly_layout, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textweeklylayout);
        convertview.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(viewHolder)convertview.getTag();
    return convertview;
}
private static class viewHolder
{
    TextView tv;
}}
```

Comment: show your WeekAdapter code

Comment: create a custom adapter

Comment: Could you please add WeakAdapter Class Code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the adapter's `getItem()` method. `gridview.getItemAtPosition()` in turns call adapter's `getItem()`-method.

Your WeekAdapter's `getItem()` returns null. That's the problem. It should be:

```
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return weekCellItems.get(arg0); 
}
```

Comment: You need to check WeakAdapter class' code. It should have a getItem() method. You should return an object at the position from getItem().

Answer (score 1):

**Add following code.**

```
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    if (weekCellItems == null || weekCellItems.size() == 0)
        return null;

    return weekCellItems.get(arg0); 
}
```

***Why :** You are implementing your custom Adapter, so you need to modify getItem() as your need.*